# Histogram of Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution

Tags: c#

The following C# source code creates a histogram of Maxwell-Boltzmann's distribution:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using ZedGraph;

public class CommonDistributions
{    
    public static double Uniform(Random random)
    {
        return random.NextDouble();
    }

    static double Gaussian(Random random)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(Uniform(random))) * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * Uniform(random));
    }
    public static double Gaussian(Random random, double mu, double sigma)
    {
        return sigma * Gaussian(random) + mu;
    }
}

public class MaxwellBolzman
{
    private static double KB = 1.38064852e-23;

    public static double MaxwellVariance(double mass, double temperature)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(KB * temperature / mass);
    }

    public static double MaxwellComponent(Random random, double mass, double temperature)
    {
        double mu = 0.0;
        double sigma = MaxwellVariance(mass, temperature);

        return CommonDistributions.Gaussian(random, mu, sigma);
    }
    public static double MaxwellSpeed(Random random, double mass, double temperature)
    {
        double one = MaxwellComponent(random, mass, temperature);
        double two = MaxwellComponent(random, mass, temperature);
        double thr = MaxwellComponent(random, mass, temperature);

        return Math.Sqrt(one * one + two * two + thr * thr);
    }
}

public static class Normalization
{
    public static int Normalize(double n_bins, double mu, double sigma, double gaussian)
    {
        var z = (mu - gaussian)/sigma;

        if (z > 3 || z < -3)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return (int)((z + 3) * n_bins / 6d);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const double N = 1000000;
        int time = (int)N;
        int binsCount = 51;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] bins = new int[binsCount];

        double mass = 14 * 1.67e-27;
        double T = 300;

        for (int i = 0; i < time; i++)
        {
            double gauss = MaxwellBolzman.MaxwellSpeed(rand, mass, T);
            double mu = MaxwellBolzman.MaxwellComponent(rand, mass, T);
            double sigma = MaxwellBolzman.MaxwellVariance(mass, T);

            int index = Normalization.Normalize(binsCount,  mu, sigma, gauss);

            if (index >= 0)
            {
                bins[index]++;
            }
        }

        PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
        for (int i = 0; i < bins.Length; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i, bins[i]);
        }

        PlotForm form = new PlotForm("Maxwell-Bolzman");
        form.AddBar(list, "Actual", Color.Blue);
        form.AxisChange();
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

[image]

Kindly, review the code.

**N.B.** The curve seems to be off the shape.

Answer (score 3):

### Static classes

You've (correctly) marked `Normalization` as `static`. You should do the same for every other class in your program - they are all currently being used as statics.

### Expression bodies

C# has a wonderful bit of syntactic sugar - [expression bodies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator#expression-body-definition) - that lets you rewrite this:

```
public static double MaxwellVariance(double mass, double temperature)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(KB * temperature / mass);
}
```

as

```
public static double MaxwellVariance(double mass, double temperature) =>
    Math.Sqrt(KB * temperature / mass);
```

### Classes

You're in C#, so you're stuck without the ability to have global functions. It's somewhat similar to Java in this way: it really pushes you to think about your code in an OOP style.

Going down this path, you would make a class to encapsulate your graph, which would take most of the code out of your `Main`. Potentially, everything up to and including the initialization of your point list could go in the constructor, and the `PlotForm` calls could go in a `plot` method. There are some advantages to this approach, including reusability, re-entrance, and testability.

As for `MaxwellBolzman` - I think you should refactor it to be a non-static class, with members for mass and temperature. `random` can be accepted as an optional parameter or the class could instantiate it itself. That will simplify many things:

- `Variance` will turn into a one-line property with an expression body
- `Component` and `Speed` will turn into parameter-less properties

### Names

This is minor, but I find the `Maxwell` prefixes in all of the methods of `MaxwellBolzman` to be redundant; I think they would be even more legible if you simply named them `Variance`, `Component` and `Speed`.

### Loops

I would find `Speed` more legible as

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    double comp = Component;
    sum += comp*comp;
}
return Math.Sqrt(sum);
```

Comment: I think the curve is not drawn properly.